# Did I set up this boundary integral for a simple square curve correctly?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

The boundary integral is: $$\tag{1}\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \cdot\hat{n}ds$$

where $\alpha$ is the value of the field on the boundary, and $\phi_{nm} = \sin(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)$. Again, we are on a square domain, so going counterclockwise, we would have the following parameterized setup: $$\cases{0\le x \le 1,0 \rightarrow &x=t, y=0 \\ 1,0\le y \le 1 \rightarrow &x=1, y=t \\ 1\ge x \ge 0,1 \rightarrow &x=-t, y=1 \\ 0,1\ge y \ge 0 \rightarrow &x=0,y=-t}$$

Here is what I think that would look like:

$\tag{2}\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \cdot\hat{n}ds = \int_0^1  \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \sqrt{1^2+0^2}dt + \\ 
\int_0^1 \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \sqrt{0+1^2}dt + \\ 
\int_1^0 \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \sqrt{-1^2+0^2}dt + 
\\ \int_1^0 \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \sqrt{0-1^2}dt$

The values of the field on the boundary are: $$\alpha = \cases{u(x,0) = x \\ u(1,y) = 1+y \\ u(x,1) = 1+x \\ u(0,y) = y}$$

plugging in these boundary conditions, and $\nabla \phi \cdot \hat{n} = \pi \Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)+m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\Big)$

$\tag{3}\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \cdot\hat{n}ds = \pi\int_0^1 x \Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y)+m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\Big) dt + \\ 
\pi \int_0^1 (1+y) \Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y) + m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\Big) dt + \\ 
\pi\int_1^0 (1+x) \Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y) + m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\Big) dt + \\ \pi\int_1^0 y \Big(n\cos(n\pi x)\sin(m\pi y) + m\sin(n\pi x)\cos(m\pi y)\Big) dt$

And then plugging in for the parameterized curves we get:

$$\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \cdot\hat{n}ds = \pi\bigg[\int_0^1 t \Big(n\cos(n\pi t)\sin(m\pi 0)+m\sin(n\pi t)\cos(m\pi 0)\Big) dt + \\ 
\int_0^1 (1+t) \Big(n\cos(n\pi 1)\sin(m\pi t) + m\sin(n\pi 1)\cos(m\pi t)\Big) dt + \\ 
\int_1^0 (1-t) \Big(n\cos(n\pi (-t))\sin(m\pi 1) + m\sin(n\pi (-t))\cos(m\pi 1)\Big) dt + \\ 
\int_1^0 -t \Big(n\cos(n\pi 0)\sin(m\pi (-t)) + m\sin(n\pi 0)\cos(m\pi (-t))\Big) dt \bigg]$$

And simplifying this down we arrive to:

$$\tag{4}\oint \alpha \nabla \phi_{nm} \cdot\hat{n}ds = \pi\bigg[m\int_0^1 t \Big(\sin(n\pi t)\Big) dt +\\ 
(-1)^n n \int_0^1 (1+t)\Big(\sin(m\pi t)\Big) dt + \\
(-1)^m m\int_1^0 (t-1) \Big(\sin(n\pi t)\Big) dt + \\
n\int_1^0 t \Big(\sin(m\pi t)\Big) dt \bigg]$$

---

Just as a sidenote: This problem came from using eigenfunction expansions to solve an inhomogeneous Poisson's Equation on a square domain for $0 \le x,y \le 1$ and for the inhomogeneous part, I needed to solve (1) subjected to the same boundary conditions